# The system can't find the file specified on CURL

Tags: curl

ALL,
I'm trying to investigate following issue:

I try to run curl as follows:

```
c:\libcurl\src\LIB-Debug>curl --verbose http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Default.aspx -F "MyFile=@11262716351.bmp;type=image/bitmap"
```

What I'm getting in response is: "The system cannot find the file specified".
The file is definitely exist in the current directory:

```
c:\libcurl\src\LIB-Debug>dir *.bmp
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is 3613-CC24

 Directory of c:\libcurl\src\LIB-Debug

27.07.2012  16:03           129 222 11262716351.bmp
               1 File(s)        129 222 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  88 206 827 520 bytes free
```

What am I doing wrong?
Trying to google didn't help as all the links refer to different issues.

Thank you.

P.S.: I can post verbose output in the pastebin for review...

Comment: Why is there an "@" in the filename. Dont think you need that.

Comment: @BenjaminTan, According to [link=http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html]this[/link] POSTing the file uses format "-F name=<@filename>;type=<file_type>" Also trying to check with WireShark the file bytes are all FF. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the service on the server was down.

Thank you for listening.